# Auto Refresh Doesn't work as i want it to work

Tags: java, android

I have an Activity called `ChatActivity` where the users are going to be messaging each other. The activity is retrieving the messages as they are sent but when messages are displayed here are's duplicates of every message.

[image]

I do have AutoRefresh but it's not refreshing the way I want it to refresh. In my Activity there is swipe refresh as well and when I swipe it refreshes properly. This is the snap when swipe refresh is used:

[image]

How can I make my Auto Refresh display my messages like how it does when I swipe to refresh it? here is my code:

```
public class ChatActivity extends AppCompatActivity {


private Toolbar mChatToolbar; //used
private String mChatUser;  //used
private String mthumb_image;
private String userName;
private String mCurrentUserId;
private TextView mUserStatus;
private EditText mChatMessageView;

private CircleImageView mProfileImage;
private FirebaseAuth mAuth;
private ImageButton mChatAddBtn;

private DatabaseReference mRootRef;
// Storage Firebase
private StorageReference mImageStorage;
private static final int GALLERY_PICK = 1;

private RecyclerView mMessagesList;
private SwipeRefreshLayout mRefreshLayout;

private ArrayList<Messages> arrayList_Messages = new ArrayList<>();

private MessageAdapter mAdapter;

private static final int TOTAL_ITEMS_TO_LOAD = 10;
private int mCurrentPage = 1;

private final Handler handler = new Handler();








@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_chat);


    mChatMessageView = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.chat_message_view);
    mChatAddBtn = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.chat_add_btn);

    mChatToolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.chat_app_bar);
    setSupportActionBar(mChatToolbar);

    ActionBar actionBar = getSupportActionBar();

    actionBar.setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
    actionBar.setDisplayShowCustomEnabled(true);

    //for Custom Action bar
    actionBar.setDisplayShowCustomEnabled(true);

    LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) getSystemService(LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
    View customBar = inflater.inflate(R.layout.chat_custom_bar,null);

    actionBar.setCustomView(customBar);

    //getting intent Data
    gettingIntentData();

    // initializing user view
    intCustomBarViewAndSetData();

    doTheAutoRefresh();


    mRootRef = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference();
    mAuth = FirebaseAuth.getInstance();
    mCurrentUserId =  mAuth.getCurrentUser().getUid();



    //------- IMAGE STORAGE ---------
    mImageStorage = FirebaseStorage.getInstance().getReference();

    mRootRef.child("Chat").child(mCurrentUserId).child(mChatUser).child("seen").setValue(true);


    LoadMessages();

    //getting information about user online or offline and thumb image
    mRootRef.child("Users").child(mChatUser).addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
        @Override
        public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {

            String thumb_image = dataSnapshot.child("thumb_image").getValue().toString();
            Picasso.with(ChatActivity.this).load(thumb_image).placeholder(R.drawable.my_profile).into(mProfileImage);

            String lastSeen = dataSnapshot.child("online").getValue().toString();

            if(lastSeen.equals("true")){
                mUserStatus.setText("Online");
            }
            else{

                //converting string into long
                Long lastTime = Long.parseLong(lastSeen);

                // creating an instance of GetTimeAgo class
                GetTimeAgo getTimeAgo = new GetTimeAgo();
                String lastSeenTime = GetTimeAgo.getTimeAgo(lastTime,getApplicationContext());
                mUserStatus.setText(lastSeenTime);
            }
        }

        @Override
        public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {

        }
    });


    //for creating chat object
    mRootRef.child("Chat").child(mCurrentUserId).addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
        @Override
        public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {

            if(!dataSnapshot.hasChild(mChatUser)){

                Map chatAddMap = new HashMap();
                chatAddMap.put("seen",false);
                chatAddMap.put("timestamp", ServerValue.TIMESTAMP);

                Map chatUserMap = new HashMap();
                chatUserMap.put("Chat/"+mCurrentUserId+"/"+mChatUser, chatAddMap);
                chatUserMap.put("Chat/"+mChatUser+"/"+mCurrentUserId, chatAddMap);

                mRootRef.updateChildren(chatUserMap, new DatabaseReference.CompletionListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onComplete(DatabaseError databaseError, DatabaseReference databaseReference) {

                        if(databaseError!= null){
                            Toast.makeText(ChatActivity.this, "Error: "+databaseError.getMessage(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

                        }
                    }
                });
            }
        }

        @Override
        public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {

        }
    });


    // Retrieving the chat messages into recyclerview
    LoadMessages();
    mRefreshLayout.setRefreshing(true);
    mRefreshLayout.setOnRefreshListener(new SwipeRefreshLayout.OnRefreshListener() {
        @Override
        public void onRefresh() {

            mCurrentPage++;

            //onRefresh remove the current messages from arraylist and load new messages
            arrayList_Messages.clear();

            // Load message
            LoadMessages();


        }
    });


}

private void doTheAutoRefresh()
{
    handler.postDelayed(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run()
        {
            LoadMessages();
            // Write code for your refresh logic
            doTheAutoRefresh();
        }
    }, 5000);
}

// Load all messages from database into recyclerView
private void LoadMessages() {

    DatabaseReference messageRef = mRootRef.child("messages").child(mCurrentUserId).child(mChatUser);

    //Query to load message per page i.e. 10
    /*
       per page load 10 message and onRefresh mCurrentpage is increment by 1
       page 1 => load 10 messages (mCurrentPage = 1 then 1*10 =10)
       page 2 => load 20 messages (mCurrentPage = 2 then 2*10 =20) and so on
     */

    Query messageQuery = messageRef.limitToLast(mCurrentPage * TOTAL_ITEMS_TO_LOAD);

    messageQuery.addChildEventListener(new ChildEventListener() {
        @Override
        public void onChildAdded(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot, String s) {

            Messages messages = dataSnapshot.getValue(Messages.class);
            arrayList_Messages.add(messages);
            mRefreshLayout.setRefreshing(true);
            mAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();

            mMessagesList.scrollToPosition(arrayList_Messages.size()-1);

            //when data load completely set refreshing
            mRefreshLayout.setRefreshing(false);
        }

        @Override
        public void onChildChanged(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot, String s) {

        }

        @Override
        public void onChildRemoved(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {

        }

        @Override
        public void onChildMoved(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot, String s) {

        }

        @Override
        public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {

        }
    });
}


// send button
public void chatSendButton(View view){

    sendMessage();
}

//sending a message
private void sendMessage() {

    String message = mChatMessageView.getText().toString().trim();

    if(!TextUtils.isEmpty(message)){

        mChatMessageView.setText("");
        String current_user_ref="messages/"+mCurrentUserId+"/"+mChatUser;
        String chat_user_ref= "messages/"+mChatUser+"/"+mCurrentUserId;

        DatabaseReference chat_push_key = mRootRef.child("messages").child(mCurrentUserId).
                child(mChatUser).push();

        String push_key = chat_push_key.getKey();

        Map messageMap = new HashMap();
        messageMap.put("message",message);
        messageMap.put("type","text");
        messageMap.put("from",mCurrentUserId);
        messageMap.put("seen",false);
        messageMap.put("time", ServerValue.TIMESTAMP);

        Map messageUserMap = new HashMap();
        messageUserMap.put(current_user_ref+ "/"+push_key,messageMap);
        messageUserMap.put(chat_user_ref+ "/"+push_key,messageMap);

        mRootRef.updateChildren(messageUserMap, new DatabaseReference.CompletionListener() {
            @Override
            public void onComplete(DatabaseError databaseError, DatabaseReference databaseReference) {

                if(databaseError!=null){
                    Log.d("TAG",databaseError.getMessage().toString());
                }
            }
        });
    }
}

//add button
public void chatAddButton(View view){
    mChatAddBtn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            Intent galleryIntent = new Intent();
            galleryIntent.setType("image/*");
            galleryIntent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT);

            startActivityForResult(Intent.createChooser(galleryIntent, "SELECT IMAGE"), GALLERY_PICK);
        }
    });


}

@Override
protected void onResume() {
    super.onResume();


}

@Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);

    if(requestCode == GALLERY_PICK && resultCode == RESULT_OK){

        Uri imageUri = data.getData();

        final String current_user_ref = "messages/" + mCurrentUserId + "/" + mChatUser;
        final String chat_user_ref = "messages/" + mChatUser + "/" + mCurrentUserId;

        DatabaseReference user_message_push = mRootRef.child("messages")
                .child(mCurrentUserId).child(mChatUser).push();

        final String push_id = user_message_push.getKey();


        StorageReference filepath = mImageStorage.child("message_images").child( push_id + ".jpg");

        filepath.putFile(imageUri).addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener<UploadTask.TaskSnapshot>() {
            @Override
            public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<UploadTask.TaskSnapshot> task) {

                if(task.isSuccessful()){

                    String download_url = task.getResult().getDownloadUrl().toString();


                    Map messageMap = new HashMap();
                    messageMap.put("message", download_url);
                    messageMap.put("seen", false);
                    messageMap.put("type", "image");
                    messageMap.put("time", ServerValue.TIMESTAMP);
                    messageMap.put("from", mCurrentUserId);

                    Map messageUserMap = new HashMap();
                    messageUserMap.put(current_user_ref + "/" + push_id, messageMap);
                    messageUserMap.put(chat_user_ref + "/" + push_id, messageMap);

                    mChatMessageView.setText("");

                    mRootRef.updateChildren(messageUserMap, new DatabaseReference.CompletionListener() {
                        @Override
                        public void onComplete(DatabaseError databaseError, DatabaseReference databaseReference) {

                            if(databaseError != null){

                                Log.d("CHAT_LOG", databaseError.getMessage().toString());

                            }

                        }
                    });


                }

            }
        });

    }

}


private void intCustomBarViewAndSetData() {
    TextView mTitleView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.custom_bar_title);
    mUserStatus = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.custom_bar_seen);
    mProfileImage = (CircleImageView) findViewById(R.id.custom_bar_image);
    mMessagesList = (RecyclerView) findViewById(R.id.messages_list);

    mMessagesList.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(this));
    mRefreshLayout = (SwipeRefreshLayout) findViewById(R.id.message_swipe_layout);
    mMessagesList.setHasFixedSize(true);

    mAdapter = new MessageAdapter(this, arrayList_Messages);
    mMessagesList.setAdapter(mAdapter);

    //showing name on toolbar
    mTitleView.setText(userName);
    mTitleView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            Intent profileIntent = new Intent(ChatActivity.this, ProfileActivity.class);
            profileIntent.putExtra("user_id", mChatUser);
            startActivity(profileIntent);
        }
    });




}

private void gettingIntentData() {
    Intent intent =getIntent();
    userName = intent.getStringExtra("Username");
    mChatUser = intent.getStringExtra("user_id");
}
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Clear the list before load in `doTheAutoRefresh()`.

```
arrayList_Messages.clear();
LoadMessages();
```

Comment: Should i put this in my doAutoRefresh method?

Comment: yes, you have to clear dataset before `LoadMessages()`.